# OpenQuery start and end date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting blank data while running query, and if i put manual date in criteria using only two '' then data is correct

```
DECLARE @strdate date,@endate date
set @strdate = '2017-06-24'
SEt @endate = '2017-06-26'
SELECT *
        FROM Openquery(E2E,'Select 
        Order_Created_at,
        Order_Number
        ,Shipping_Postcode
        ,Payment_Method
        ,Order_item
        ,Item_sku
        ,Item_Unit_Price 
        from sales_order_export_summary Where Date(Order_Created_at) >= '''' + @strdate + '''' AND Date(Order_Created_at) <= ''''+@endate + ''''')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the date to string preferably in ISO format before concatenate

```
 Where Date(Order_Created_at) >= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @strdate, 112) + ''' AND
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables in OPENQUERY, you have to use dynamic SQL. I've changed variables `@strdate` and `@enddate` to `varchar(10)`, because I wasn't able to concat strings.

```
DECLARE @strdate varchar(10),@endate varchar(10)
SET @strdate = '2017-06-24'
SET @endate = '2017-06-26'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX) = '
SELECT *
        FROM Openquery(E2E,''Select 
        Order_Created_at,
        Order_Number
        ,Shipping_Postcode
        ,Payment_Method
        ,Order_item
        ,Item_sku
        ,Item_Unit_Price 
        from sales_order_export_summary Where Date(Order_Created_at) >= ''''' + @strdate + ''''' AND Date(Order_Created_at) <= '''''+@endate + ''''''')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql) for `OPENQUERY`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explains the issue with format. Here is another easy way to do it but may not be efficient

```
DECLARE @strdate date,@endate date
set @strdate = '2017-06-24'
SEt @endate = '2017-06-26'
SELECT *
FROM   Openquery(E2E, 'Select 
        Order_Created_at,
        Order_Number
        ,Shipping_Postcode
        ,Payment_Method
        ,Order_item
        ,Item_sku
        ,Item_Unit_Price 
        from sales_order_export_summary')
WHERE  Order_Created_at >= @strdate
       AND Order_Created_at < Dateadd(dd, 1, @endate)
```